# Tkinter - Underlining button text

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Button text underline option, is not working. This is what I've tried:

```
    boldFontOpts = tkFont.Font(weight='bold')
    self.boldButton = Button(self.toolbarFrame, text='B', command=self.boldfunc, 
        width=bWidth, height=bHeight)
    self.boldButton['font'] = boldFontOpts
    self.boldButton.grid(sticky=W, padx='4', row=1, column = 0)

    self.underlineButton = Button(self.toolbarFrame, text='U', command=self.underlinefunc,
        width=bWidth, height=bHeight)
    underlineFontOpts = tkFont.Font(self.underlineButton, self.underlineButton.cget('font'))
    underlineFontOpts.configure(underline=True)
    self.underlineButton.configure(font=underlineFontOpts)
    self.underlineButton.grid(sticky=W, padx='3', row=1, column = 1)
```

The code used for the underline button (which doesn't work) was taken from:
[Underline Text in Tkinter Label widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655449/underline-text-in-tkinter-label-widget)

I also used the code for the bold button (which works) for the underline button, however it doesn't work when the `weight='bold'` is substituted with `underline=1` or `underline=True` and all appropriate variable names etc. are changed (obviously).

So, how can this button text be underlined?

Additional info:
- On mac
- Python 3
- tinter 8.5

Edit:
I added these two lines:

```
font = tkFont.Font(font=self.underlineButton['font'])
print(font.actual())
```

And in the terminal it says `'underline': 1`, yet still does not display the underline.

Comment: Yes, I'll add to question

Answer (score 2):

```
tkinter.Button(self, text='Reset',relief='flat',font=('Verdana', 9,'bold','underline'))
```

Comment: Please review [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the button, try doing something like this:

```
button = Button(window, text="Sample", font= "Verdana 10 underline")
```

This then sets the font of the button to an underlined style.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Still not displaying an underline, if I change the code you have and put `font="Verdana 10 bold"` it goes bold though.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's because you're on a Mac, try looking at some tkFonts documentation, sorry I wasn't much help! I can't really probe your issue.